# Save to a network location in Python

Tags: python, networking, file-sharing

I set up a Pi as a file server. So from my pc or other pis I can easily add and remove files. I can do it manually no problem. So, with my other Pi's, I want to save to the network folder, but I can't figure out the directory. Currently I have

```
directory = '////mastercamera//PiShare//'
camera.capture(directory + ip = '.jpg' format='jpeg')
```

I've tried smb://mastercameara/PiShare, //mastercamera/Pishare, but no matter what it says no such directory.

Answer (score 1):

Python can only easily access local paths, not network paths.
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297355/accessing-shared-smb-ubuntu-in-python-scripts) for a similar question with a suggested fix.